how to calculate ratio in group by in pandas
I have the following pandas dataframe



ts
tenant
result




1
t1
pass


1
t1
pass


1
t2
pass


2
t1
fail


2
t1
fail


2
t2
fail


2
t1
pass


2
t2
pass


3
t1
pass


3
t1
pass


3
t2
pass



i want to perform something that will be similar to the following SQL statement
select
 ts,
 tenant,
 count(case result when 'fail' then 1 else 0) / count(1)
from tbl 
group by ts, tenant

that will result with the following dataframe



ts
tenant
fail_ratio




1
t1
0.0


1
t2
0.0


2
t1
0.666


2
t2
0.5


3
t1
0.0


3
t2
0.0



I dont really understand how i can do this. Is it possible to do it directly on the dataframe or would i require intermediate dataframes? would i need to do it more programmatically and iterate over the groups?
The end game here is to create timeseries data on the fail ratio per tenant to plot.
Thanks,

Convert "result" to boolean and perform a groupby.mean to compute the number of "fail" relative to the total. The boolean values will behave like 0/1 when aggregated as mean:
out = (df['result'].eq('fail')
       .groupby([df['ts'], df['tenant']]).mean()
       .reset_index(name='fail_ratio')
      )

Alternative syntax:
out = (df.assign(fail_ratio=df['result'].eq('fail'))
         .groupby(['ts', 'tenant'], as_index=False)['fail_ratio'].mean()
      )

Output:
   ts tenant  fail_ratio
0   1     t1    0.000000
1   1     t2    0.000000
2   2     t1    0.666667
3   2     t2    0.500000
4   3     t1    0.000000
5   3     t2    0.000000


The first approach is preferable as the second one will clone the whole df object due to .assign, which can tax the memory if df is large.

@QuangHoang that's a good point. I provided this as a generic case if OP wants to use multiple aggregations.

A possible solution, which uses:

groupby to group the dataframe df by the columns ts and tenant, with as_index=False to keep the grouping columns as separate columns in the result.

agg to aggregate the result column using a lambda function that calculates the proportion of fail values in each group. The lambda function uses eq to check if each value in result is equal to fail, sum to count the number of fail values, and divides by the total number of values in the group using len(x).


(df.groupby(['ts', 'tenant'], as_index=False)
 .agg(fail_ratio = ('result', lambda x: x.eq('fail').sum() / len(x))))

Output:
   ts tenant  fail_ratio
0   1     t1    0.000000
1   1     t2    0.000000
2   2     t1    0.666667
3   2     t2    0.500000
4   3     t1    0.000000
5   3     t2    0.000000


Another approach is .groupby().value_counts():
(df.groupby(['ts', 'tenant'])['result']
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack('result', fill_value=0)['fail']
   .reset_index(name='fail_rate')
)

Output:
   ts tenant  fail_rate
0   1    t1    0.000000
1   1    t2    0.000000
2   2    t1    0.666667
3   2    t2    0.500000
4   3    t1    0.000000
5   3    t2    0.000000

